# Что происходит с пользователями, которые скачали бета-версию приложения?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Такой вопрос, например, сейчас приложение находится на бета-тестировании в Google Play, что произойдет с пользователями, когда приложение выйдет в release? У них обновится приложения до версии, которая в release? Пользователи, которые скачали бету-версию будут показываться, как пользователи, которые скачали приложение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут будут 2 варианта, которые на самом деле между собой мало отличаются в плане результата:

1. Например, у вас в БЕТА была версия 3. В релиз вы выпускаете версию 4. В этом случае все, кто пользовался БЕТА 3 обновятся до РЕЛИЗ 4 (т. к. это одно и то же приложение, с одним и тем же пакетом)
2. Например, у вас в БЕТА была версия 3, и вы ее же переносите в релиз. Никто ни до чего не обновится, но всем станет доступна версия 3.

В любом случае, приложение всегда обновляется до последней доступной версии.

Разница будет в другом случае:  Если у вас в релизе версия 4, и вы выпустили в БЕТА версию 5, то версия 4 будет доступна всем, а версия 5 - только бета-тестерам.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! А например, если 100 юзером скачали приложение во время бета-тестирования версии 1, когда приложение выходит в релиз, будет ли показано, что 100 человек скачало приложение? Или отсчет начинается с момента релиза?

Comment: @Lucky_girl, врятли кто-то такие тонкости знает) Но, скорее всего, будет показано, что 100 человек установило. Сужу по тому, что бета-версий установки консолью считаются, а число юзеров когда-либо ставивших приложение соответствует кол-ву установок, отображающихся в маркете.